# jQuery: tbody > tr selector not working for .hover() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, html-table

I have a xhtml page which I am mostly managing with Knockout.JS, but for the simple DOM manipulations I am using jQuery.

This is the table that I have:

```
 <table style="font-size: small; margin-left: -1em;
                           border-right: transparent; border-bottom: transparent;" 
                           id="appointmentsTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="display: none;">id</th>
                                <th class="hand-on-hover" data-bind="click: sortByDate">
                                    #{bigcopy.tableDate} <i id="appDateCri"></i>
                                </th>
                                <th>#{bigcopy.tableTime}</th>
                                <th class="hand-on-hover" data-bind="click: sortByName">
                                    #{bigcopy.tableClient} <i id="appNameCri"></i>
                                </th>
                                <th class="hand-on-hover" data-bind="click: sortByType">
                                    #{bigcopy.tableType} <i id="appTypeCri"></i>
                                </th>
                                <th>#{bigcopy.tableMessage}</th>
                                <th>#{bigcopy.tableEmail}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="fbody" data-bind="foreach: appointments">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="display: none;" data-bind="text:id"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text:date"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text:time"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text:clientName"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text:type"></td>
                                <td style="max-width: 15em;" data-bind="text:message"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text:email"></td>
                                <td style="border: transparent; display: none;">
                                    <span style="color:#d9534f;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span style="color: #f0ad4e; margin-left: 0.75em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

As you see the last td in the tbody > tr is hidden. It will hold buttons to edit/delete appointments from the table. My intention is to only show it when the row is hovered:

```
$("#appointmentsTable > tbody > tr").hover(                
            function () {
                //mouseover
                console.log("hovered");
                $(this).find("td:last").css("display", "block");
            }, function () {
        //mouseout
        $(this).find("td:last").css("display", "none");
    });
```

I have entered the console.log() statement there to at least see if the selector is recognized by jQuery. Unfortunately that is not the case. However changing the selector to:

```
 $("#appointmentsTable tr").hover
```

and the handler to:

```
$(this).css("background-color", "red");
```

...diligently paints the background of the header to red. To strip-off possible questions, this is I how I obtained the selector:

[image]

..I then right-clicked and chose: **Copy** -> **selection**

Any hint will be appreciated.It may have something to do with the .xhtml extension of the page, but there's no alternative for me - I cannot use a h:dataTable because the table is populated and updated from a REST-resource.

Comment: I am not sure what your bug is, but I would like to suggest to use $(ele).css('display','table-cell'); instead of 'block'.

Comment: The thing is the code doesn't get inside the 'mouseover' function

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some bug on jQuery-KO-xhtml compatibility. I've tried tons of things including xPath, setting custom ids (having a certain pattern) to each tr. Nothing worked. I just couldn't shoot past the 'tbody'. In the end end I implemented an easy decision using Knockout.JS:

I added this to the appointment class:

```
sch.Appointment = function (id, date, time, type, clientName, email, message) {
    ...
    var self = this;
    self.displayEdits = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleEdits = function () {
        self.displayEdits(!self.displayEdits());
    };
};
```

and these bindings to the 'tr' and 'td' elements:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: appointments">
                            <tr data-bind="event: {mouseover: toggleEdits, mouseout: toggleEdits}">
                                ...
                                <td data-bind="visible: displayEdits" style="border: transparent; display: none;">
                                    <span style="color:#d9534f;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span style="color: #f0ad4e; margin-left: 0.75em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

I hope it will be helpful to anyone.